# Visual Studio 2022 don't display errors on .cshtml files

Tags: visual-studio, razor, visual-studio-2022

I just installed VisualStudio 2022 some days ago and I realized that it is not showing me the errors that I made in the views (.cshtml files) for example something simple as:

```
@{
 var MyNumber = 1;
 mynumber = 3
}
```

Visual studio doesn't recognize the variable that does not exist or that the assign does not end with ';' and then it doesn't underline it or remark it in red and It's very annoying to be honest. It does not happen for my old instance VS2017

VS2022:
[Code Image from VS2022](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lvor3.png)
VS2017:
[Code Image from VS2017](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QzfAA.png)

I've been researching about and already tried solutions like delete the .suo file or the .vs folder on the project. Also tried clearing Cache, even reinstalling Visual Studio like 3 times.

If anyone could help me it would be pretty awesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem disappeared after updating the Visual Studio (VS).

Comment: Marked as answer because after lot of reinstalls it is working now, so I gess on some update between was just fixed